# Refrigerate Cookie Filling with heavy whipping cream?

Tags: milk, cream, icing, filling

Is it necessary to refrigerate cookies that have been filled with icing of heavy whipping cream, butter, and milk chocolate chips?

Answer (score 2):

Your ingredients imply that you are working with some version of ganache (or truffle filling).

The lighter kinds, with a lower chocolate  and higher milk or cream content will need refrigeration. Very high-chocolate versions can be held at cool room temperature for a limited time.

Without further examining the recipe and method, food safety considerations mean we can only answer your question with:

> Yes, the cookies need to be stored in a refrigerator.